# context.filter not working on safari

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm building a drawing app with react and on safari, `context.filter` is not working properly. Find below the rendered on chrome and firefox and the rendered on safari. Is there an alternative to this for safari?

[image: chrome]

[image]

Comment: For an alternative, it seems that your drawing could be made with a shadowBlur.

Comment: @Kaiido can you give an example using shadowBlur to have blur effect

Comment: @SavinaChandla I said that only regarding OP's graphic, it's not sure at all yours could also be done this way. But quickly made, https://jsfiddle.net/q72s8hok/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context.filter does not support in safari

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter

I don't have an idea about your project but you can use canvas library like http://ocanvas.org/, http://paperjs.org/
or make your idea with the SVG library like [rapheal](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/)

Comment: can you please suggest which library would solve the problem of canvas blur filter issue in ios safari/chrome. I face this issue where blur filter doesn't work in ios safari/chrome in my vue.js project. But the documentation for both these libraries is not much clear on how to use them.

Comment: Here is a polyfill: https://github.com/davidenke/context-filter-polyfill

Comment: polyfill is not working! @AdamTaylor